# how to display a webpage inside(or under) flash(as3, not flex)

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, jquery-ui

I am developing a web game. Now i need to display a webpage, in a dialog, within my game stage.

And i know a solution, using jqueryui:

```
<div id="swf"></div> <!-- this will be replaced by game flash object -->
<div id="myDialog">
    <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        open: function(ev, ui){
            $("#myFrame").attr("src", "http://xxx");
        }
    });
</script>
```

This solution need me to set "wmode" of flash object to be "opaque".

But for performance, i need to use "wmode=direct", and if i use "wmode=direct", the jquery dialog has some ploblem: titlebar is hided behind flash object, so that, i cannot drag(move) the dialog or close the dialog.

Are there other solution, without changing "wmode"? I've seen a solution, but i don't know how to do it. here are some code generated by that solution:

```
<iframe class="dialog_mask" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="about:blank" style="visibility: visible; left: 331px; top: 88px; width: 702px; height: 481px;"></iframe>
<div class="dialog_wrap" style="visibility: visible; left: 331px; top: 88px; width: 700px; z-index: 5007;">
    <div class="dialog_header" style="cursor: move;">
        <h3>the title</h3>
        <button title="close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog_content" style="height: 450px;">
        <iframe class="dialog_frame" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" src="http://xxx" style="width: 700px; height: 450px;"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" ...><param name="wmode" value="window"></object>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the #myDialog div a height and width greater than your flash SWF.

Comment: why? the title is hidden because of wmode, not position.